# couchdb POST method not supported in local instance

Tags: couchdb

My local instance of couchdb seems not to support the POST method.

This is the answer I have from chrome dev tools

```
POST http://localhost:5984/epos-couch/_design/epos-couch/_view/ri 415 (Unsupported Media Type)
```

the code in use is a simple ajax request with post method set:

```
$.ajax({ 
                    async: true, 
                    url: ajaxURL,
                    type:"POST",
                    data:.....,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    timeout:5000,
                    success:function(response){

                        riResponseList=response.rows;
                        },
                    error:function(){
                        alert('fetching error');
                        }
                    });
```

I'm pretty sure the problem is in my local instance because running such code on [cloudant.com](https://cloudant.com/)  everyhing works fine.

So my question is: how can I set my local instance of couchdb to support the POST method?

I searched on the interet a bit (http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb, http://guide.couchdb.org/) but couln't find an answer.

Comment: You should change the POST to GET first (to test the query is working)

Comment: The query works because when I run it on the remote server (cloudant) it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify `contentType: "application/json"` in your `$.ajax` call, as some configurations of CouchDB choke when they receive a non-`application/json` POST body.

Comment: many many thanks! Correct AND +1. It was a while I was stuck on this issue.