# Batch get ids with docs included?

Tags: javascript, typescript, couchdb

I use a common request library, `node-fetch`, to get a number of documents including docs. But the couchDB server returns status code `415` (Unsupported Media Type). What is wrong in the request?

Is include docs not allowed?
is the body incorrect?
Something else?

```
public getDocuments(databaseName: string, ids: string[]): Promise<ICouchDBDocumentDoc[]> {
    return fetch(`${this.baseUrl}/${databaseName}/_bulk_get?include_docs=true`, {
        headers: this.headers,
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({ keys: ids }),
    })
        .then((response) => {
            return this.responseHandler(response);
        })
        .then((response) => {
            // doc can be null if the item is deleted
            console.log('docs');
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
            return response;
        });
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [couchdb POST method not supported in local instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10928814/couchdb-post-method-not-supported-in-local-instance)

Answer (score 4):

The request header does not contain the content type. You need to specify it:

```js
headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
```